# automatically update audit columns in a table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have created a table in my application and added the auditing columns :

- last_updated
- last_updated_by
- created_by
- created_on

I would like to have a mechanism in the db to automatically populate these columns, on searching I found this link https://dailypostgres.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/keep-track-of-table-data-changes-by-putting-auditing-columns-and-populate-it-automatically-using-trigger/ and used the following code to create a function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_audit_columns 
     (IN p_table_name TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS 
$body$
DECLARE      
       x_function_name               TEXT;      
       str_build                     TEXT;  
BEGIN      
     IF LENGTH(p_table_name) = 0      
     THEN          
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'P_TABLE_NAME IS REQUIRED TO GENERATE TRIGGER';

     END IF;        

     -- trigger function name based on table name passed as param 
     x_function_name := 'trg_audit_'  || p_table_name || '()';    

     -- build string to create trigger function
     str_build :=    'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ' || x_function_name ||  '   
                      RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $TRIGGER$
BEGIN
 IF TG_OP = ''INSERT'' 
 THEN
     NEW.last_updated  := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
     NEW.last_updated_by  := SESSION_USER;
     NEW.created_by   := SESSION_USER;
     NEW.created_on   := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
     RETURN NEW;

 ELSIF TG_OP = ''UPDATE'' 
 THEN
     NEW.last_updated := SESSION_USER;
     NEW.last_updated_by := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
     RETURN NEW;

 END IF;

END;
$TRIGGER$
LANGUAGE ''plpgsql'' EXTERNAL SECURITY DEFINER;';

     EXECUTE str_build;

     EXECUTE 'DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS audit_trigger ON '|| p_table_name ||';';

     -- create trigger which actually calls above function
     str_build := 'CREATE TRIGGER audit_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE '
               || ' ON '|| p_table_name
               || ' FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE '|| x_function_name ||';';

     EXECUTE str_build;

     RETURN;

END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE CALLED ON NULL INPUT SECURITY DEFINER;
```

But even now when I try to insert/update a row the columns are not getting populated automatically.
Although I can see in the pgAdmin ui that the function is created.

Is there something that I am missing ? Also as I am pretty new to this can you please explain what this script is trying to accomplish ?

Comment: You should call that function with the table name you want to audit. F.ex. `SELECT update_audit_columns('my_table')` -- BTW its logic is a complete mess. You don't need a separate trigger function for each table (thus you don't need this function). A single trigger function can be called from different triggers.

Comment: Hey, thanks, that made it work!!
I am completely new to this kind of functionality, could you please elaborate on how this is not required/optimal way to do this and the alternate solution you have ?